# Set Rules in Seeds.rb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seeding, faker

all. I'm currently adding to my `seeds.rb` file in Rails using the `faker` gem. I'm wondering: how do you get the fake data to follow "the rules" I want?

I'm building a basketball statistics application. I want `stat` in `seeds` to create 300 sets of statistics where all the criteria I have set in the `stat` model are true. Right now, only 7-9 of the 300 sets of data end up being created. Is there a way to get `seeds` to ignore the models that don't work and make 300 that do?

For instance, I want field goal attempts (`fga` in my db) to be greater or equal to field goals made (`fg`). (I have this "rule" set up in my model.) When I do this in my seeds file:

```
# seeds.rb snippet     
300.times do    
 stat = Stat.create(
        fg: Faker::Number.between(0, 15),
        fga: Faker::Number.between(0, 20)
        # more stats below
 )
```

how do I make sure that `fga` is >= `fg` every time?

Do I have to say specifically in `seeds` that `fg` can't be greater than `fga`? Or do I set a method in my `stat.rb` model file and `Faker` will follow it? (I have a few other rules on my model, otherwise I would just set the fake numbers differently.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
until Stat.count >= 300 do
  Stat.create(
    fg: Faker::Number.between(0, 15),
    fga: Faker::Number.between(0, 20)
    # more stats below
  )
end
```

Comment: Never thought I'd thank mad cow for anything, but thanks, @madcow!